# how can I index an array by it's name in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I have such bash code below, I just want to know how to find an array by it's name:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=("object1" "object2")

name="arr"

array=${!name}
echo object0 = ${array[0]}
echo object1 = ${array[1]}
```

outputs below:

```
object0 = object1
object1 =
```

I'm wondering why I cannot index the second element and how can I do that!!!

Comment: You fail to get the second element because `$arr` when `arr` is an array yields the zeroth element of the array (only).  So the assignment `array=${!name}` assigns a single value to `array`, and then you can't pick up multiple values from it.

Comment: Thank you, I googled it, and now I understand what does '@' mean!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
name="arr[@]"
array=("${!name}")
```

Your other code is fine.

Or if you have this passed as a variable, `name="arr"`

You can always use this hack:

```
name_temp="$name[@]"
array=("${!name_temp}")
```

Comment: Thanks, this really solve my problem, yeah, I have the output that I expected!